VTC Statistics (last week)
My take on it.
We do have legitimate disagreements regarding the framework and overall purpose of Philosophy meta. And they might not be easily reconcilable.
But the real disruption and damage is done by a few individuals. Mods should be able to talk to them and find some common ground.
#Number of VTC votes during last week:

Shoudn’t the obscurantism of the supernatural automatically deem it extremely implausible? [closed]
Shoudn’t the obscurantism of the supernatural automatically deem it extremely implausible?
Can we live life without "beliefs" or "leaps of faith"? [closed]
Can we live life without "beliefs" or "leaps of faith"?
What is the overlap between philosophy and physics? [closed]
What is the overlap between philosophy and physics?
Does silence have a role to play in the philosophical dialectic? [closed]
Does silence have a role to play in the philosophical dialectic?
Is God even more improbable than the origin of life? [closed]
Is God even more improbable than the origin of life?
Should (/does) metaphysics care about physics? [closed]
Should (/does) metaphysics care about physics?
Rationally speaking, should we have a certain style of proof, or evidence, in order to fundamentally change our practices? [closed]
Rationally speaking, should we have a certain style of proof, or evidence, in order to fundamentally change our practices?
How do you differentiate between fiction and reality? [closed]
How do you differentiate between fiction and reality?
Emergent Dualism in continuation of Non-Reductive Physicalism - a mighty struggle to explain the evolution of the human mind? [closed]
Emergent Dualism in continuation of Non-Reductive Physicalism - a mighty struggle to explain the evolution of the human mind?
Epistemic Concern Regarding Black Holes [closed]
Epistemic Concern Regarding Black Holes
Is this why we can't understand the "begining of time"? [closed]
Is this why we can't understand the "begining of time"?
Why is creationism even an issue? [closed]
Why is creationism even an issue?
What explains the definition of true and false in untyped lambda calculus? [closed]
What explains the definition of true and false in untyped lambda calculus?
Is there any proof of existence of any higher being who created us? [closed]
Is there any proof of existence of any higher being who created us?
Can you cross the same temporal boundary twice? [closed]
Can you cross the same temporal boundary twice?
Is it possible to visualize higher dimensional space? [closed]
Is it possible to visualize higher dimensional space?
Which cosmological philosophy has stronger arguments? [closed]
Which cosmological philosophy has stronger arguments?
Physical and non-physical [closed]
Physical and non-physical

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
